# PyopenGL glReadPixels

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I tried to use the glReadPixels method to color code a simple triangle in the screen, just without any secondary render functions, etc. but it didn't give the good result. Code:

```python
import pygame as pg
from OpenGL.GL import *


pg.display.set_mode((500,500),pg.OPENGL)
glClearColor(0.5,0.0,0.5,0.0)
done=0

def first():
    glColor3f(0.5,0.6,0.7)
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    glVertex(0.0,0.0,0.0)
    glVertex(1.0,0.0,0.0)
    glVertex(0.0,1.0,0.0)
    glEnd()
cl=0
clock=pg.time.Clock()
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type==pg.QUIT: done=1
        elif event.type==pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos=pg.mouse.get_pos()
            color=glReadPixels(pos[0],pos[1],1,1,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT)
            print color, pos[0], pos[1])



    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    first()
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
pg.quit()
```

But it always gives the SAME color output:
[[[ 0.50196081  0.          0.50196081]]] 288 217
How can I fix it?

Comment: As far as I can see from the code, you are reading back the contents of the back buffer which are _undefined_ at this point in time. I don't know how pygame's `mouse.get_pos()` is supposed to work, but I suspect that it is not returning the correct OpenGL windows coordinates with the origin at bottom loft corner. From the numbers given, on a 500x500 window, and assuming identity transforms and full viewport, (288,217) is just the background, not in the triangle at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that [glReadPixels](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) accepts bottom-left origin and pygame gives top-left.

First, you should always save your pygame `Surface` (for the reason I will soon demonstrate). So:

```
window = pg.display.set_mode((500,500),pg.OPENGL)
```

Now you can access `window.width` and `window.height`. So now your `glReadPixels` will get the proper place:

```
color=glReadPixels(x,window.height-y,1,1,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT)
```

PS: If you do want the *most recent* color, you should just put your colour detection after `first()` but before `pg.display.flip()` (OpenGL is always bound to the back buffer (unless you were to specify otherwise (but you wouldn't want to)))

EDIT: pg, not py

EDIT: I was wrong, it's in pixels. My bad.

Comment: Thanks! But tell me, why theese returned colors isn't the same with the color values that I described the `glClearColor` & the `glColor`?

Comment: That is a good question... does pygame automatically clear the back buffer? It's possible that because you're reading from your back buffer you're getting empty memory. (See my "PS")